# Filter WHEN MATCHED not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
MERGE [TenantSync].[ReportingSync] AS MyTarget
USING [TenantSync].[ReportingSyncStage] AS MySource
ON MySource.[TenantID] = MyTarget.[TenantID] AND MySource.[ServiceID] = MyTarget.[ServiceID]
WHEN MATCHED AND [MyTarget].[Modified] <> MySource.[Modified]
    THEN UPDATE SET [FTOP_EntitlementCount] = MySource.FTOP_EntitlementCount, Modified = MySource.Modified 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT ([TenantID], [ServiceID], [FTOP_EntitlementCount], [Modified]) 
        VALUES (MySource.[TenantID], MySource.[ServiceID], MySource.[FTOP_EntitlementCount], MySource.[Modified])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE
```

I realized that I was updating all rows from MySource to MyTarget even if the Modified date hadn't changed so I added the "AND [MyTarget].[Modified] <> MySource.[Modified]" to the WHEN MATCHED expecting it to update the records who's Modified date doesn't match. I set all the modified dates in ReportingSync to null. Ran the merge statement and it processes quickly with no affected records.

Ideas?

Comment: ``NULL`` is not a value. Try this ( [MyTarget].[Modified] <> MySource.[Modified] OR [MyTarget].[Modified] IS NULL)

Comment: Also, please [be very careful using `MERGE`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). Most of these issues haven't been addressed, even though this year we will see the 6th major release since `MERGE` was added.

Comment: I'm used to dealing with null values but I would have expected comparing two fields to know that they don't match. I added the OR [MyTarget].[Modified] IS NULL and it immediate populated the Modified fields. I ran the merge again and no updated were performed which is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

It is not "true" that `NULL <> 'some non-null value'`.

When using ANSI NULLS (which is default for SQL Server), the only thing that is ever true about NULL is that it `IS NULL`.